# Filter my Excel data file on certain parameters using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have a file named ProductList.xlsx which has following data:[My Original data file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7iVE.png)

Parameters required for my data : [Parameters Required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5Snx.png)

If a particular row doesn't have any one of given requirement then I want that row to be deleted and add to new excel file "Errors.xlsx"

I am new to this and don't know which method to use to filter my data.
Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Are you doing this in a client program (Console, WinForms, WPF), or on a server (or a service)? You need very different approaches

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to achieve this with C# you can use an external library. Like [ExcelLibrary](https://github.com/gustafl/ExcelLibrary) for example.

But I would suggest that you take a look at macros programmed with Visual Basic for Applications. It's integrated with Microsoft Office and there are a lot of free and easy [tutorials](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/create-a-macro.html).